# Xcode always freezes when switching branches

Tags: xcode, git

When using Xcode 8's built-in source control, switching between two branches almost always causes Xcode to freeze and requires force quitting the app. My branches aren't particularly worlds apart. Doesn't seem like it's guzzling excessive memory or CPU either. What's the deal?

Comment: Same here. Xcode 8, MacOS 10.12 Sierra

iMac: 3.2GHz i5, 12GB RAM

Comment: I'm also seeing this behavior when making a commit or even simply staging a chuck of code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Turns out this is a known issue in Xcode 8 and 8.1.

[image]

It may be that your workspace or project is saved in iCloud. I turned off automatic saving of Desktop folders to iCloud, and moved my workspace from iCloud to my local desktop, and it works fine now.

Comment: I'm on El Capiton. Xcode 8. Experiencing frequent crashes. I am using [this](http://www.imore.com/how-save-your-desktop-and-documents-folder-icloud-drive-macos-sierra) link. But since my my OS isn't Sierra nor it there is anything named "Desktop and Document folders" once I click on Options. Any advice? What I did for right now was that I just **disabled iCloud Drive**. Waiting for it to see if it works